# Working with date and time in Attendance app

Tags: java, android, sql-server

How can I avoid duplication of data for example when the user click clock in his information will be entered in the database so I don't need that button anymore I want to hide (disable) it till the next day the same thing with the clock out button...

how can I do that

Comment: some kind of timer?  testing against current time? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you tried any? Show us the way.

Comment: store the time the user clicked the button, and checkif the day has passed - enable it back

Answer (score 0):

You can store date when he clicks on the clock (ie.  punches in or out)  in shared preferences and while retrieving put following condition :

```
If(savedDate < todaysDate) {
    // enable here
} else {
    // disable
}
```

How to use shared preference ? Check [here](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/Unit%204/91_p_shared_preferences.html).